# Show random image from a folder only once in VB.NET?

Tags: image

I would like a random picture from a folder in my computer to be shown in a picturebox but every image has to be shown **only once**!

Is this possible?

This is what I managed to find:

```
Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim alljpgs() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\ImageFolder", "*.*", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    Dim jpg As New Bitmap(alljpgs(rnd.Next(0, alljpgs.Count - 1)))
    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = jpg
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry... I just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim alljpgs() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\ImageFolder", "*.*", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
Dim seenJpgs as new List(of string)
Dim jpg As Bitmap
do
    jpg = New Bitmap(alljpgs(rnd.Next(0, alljpgs.Count - 1)))
    if not seenJpgs.any(function(seenJpg) seenJpg = jpg) then
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = jpg
        seenJpgs.add(jpg)
        break
    end if
loop while true
```

You'll need to persist the seenJpgs variable across calls. The way to do this depends largely on the technologies your using (asp.net, wpf, winforms, etc), but if your in a stateful app the easiest solution is to put this in a class and declare seenJpgs as a shared property.